# Increase font size of RecyclerView items

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a navigation bar with `RecyclerView` that has different items. I wish to change the font size of it.
Here is the code for *`navigation_menu.xml`*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/app_background"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/nav_header_main" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Try this [`custom navigationView using RecyclerView`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50252939/change-background-color-of-single-specific-menu-items-of-navigationview)

Comment: what don't you modify it directly in the recycler's item layout ?

Comment: How are you setting up your adapter?

Comment: Modify your single item view text size.

Comment: Item in RecyclerView is in separate xml. So posting your xml of RecyclerView here is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and easiest way i think about is change the font size directly in your single item.
But if for some reason you dont want to do so, try to read this: [Android change TextView textSize on RecyclerView adapter from Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42641758/android-change-textview-textsize-on-recyclerview-adapter-from-activity)